# How to resolve %DNX_PATH% in development environment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a partially developed ASP.NET 5 application. The application has the following three sub projects:

- Web
- Web.API
- Auth.Server

The Web project relies on the Auth.Server for the OAuth implementation and redirects to that project on load. There's some configuration related to the httpPlatform handler in the Web project's web.config.

```
<httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" />
```

This throws a **Bad Gateway** error related to the **httpPlatformHandler** when I run or view in browser the Web project from VS2015. However I've tried publishing the site locally and hosting in IIS with httpPlatformHandler (version 1.2) installed on IIS which actually works.

I could see that this creates an approot folder with a web.cmd file that has **%DNX_PATH%** variable defined and that the web.config in wwwroot refers this particular approot/web.cmd file for the processPath attribute.

Question: What location should I point the processPath in the development environment?

I'm new to ASP.NET 5 and only have some basic reading under my belt.

Comment: Did you got any clue on this?